# Elasticsearch date format on mapping not working

Tags: date, elasticsearch, format, mapping

I am trying to find the appropriate date format for the following example :

```
Tue Jul 25 2017 15:13:07 GMT+0000
```

I tried many format on the ES mapping but none worked for me!

I tried those :

```
E M d yyyy HH:mm:ss z
E M d yyyy HH:mm:ss Z
EEE MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format for this is :

```
E MMM d y HH:mm:ss zZ
```